# Profile pic displaying for all users rather than one

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Hi guys so i am trying to create my profile pics for my users to upload. I have got it to work for the users, so you can log in upload etc, and then logout , all works fine, however at the moment it is showing every users profile pic and not the specific one which is logged in at the time

```
id 
user_name
password 
profilePic set it as text
```

MY PHP:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect");
mysql_select_db("reg") or die ("could not find db");
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['username']){
  header("location: login.php");
}

$favs = array();
$links = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE fav='yes'";
$records = mysql_query($sql);
//while($result =mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
//$favs[] = $result['recipeName'];
//$links[] =    $result['url'];
//}
$user_name =    $_SESSION['username'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
      "Image/userImages/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","reg");
  $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET profilePic = '".
      $_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE user_name = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
}

?>
```

html:

```
<div class = "pic">
  <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","reg");
  $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
    if($row['profilePic'] == ""){
      echo "<img width='100' height='100' 
        src='Image/userImages/profile.png' alt='Default Profile Pic'>";
    } else {
      echo "<img width='100' height='100' 
        src='Image/userImages/".$row['profilePic']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
  }
  ?>

  <div class="userNameText">
    <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is something to do with this: `$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");` I tried changing that to `$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = $user_name");` but no luck so went back to something which almost worked. Anyway any help on this matter would be amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
```

to

```
$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users where user_name = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

you forgot to add `' '` to where, if that html is in the same file as the php, then you can use $user_name if not, you have to use session

Comment: Perfect :) my bad hahah, will accpet in 6 mins when i can x